# c++:Is it possible to define overloaded operators ind drived class that will work objs base class type

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Is it possible to define overloaded operators in drived class that will work objs  from base class type?

for example:lets say i have a class Point and i want to do all the operator overloading in a class named Operators that will inherit Point class

is it possible?if not, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: If you had tried it, you would have seen that it is possible.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'd be news to me if it is. Doesn't seem like a good design to me.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore oops, I misread the question as "define overloaded operators in base class that will work objs from derived class type"

Comment: @SethCarnegie huh, I thought so, you scared me there :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore when I of all people make some ludicrous statement like that, you can be pretty sure it's wrong :) My brain probably read it in correctly but saw that it was the wrong way around and switched it before my mind got to comprehend it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Besides, your approach is wrong. Inheritance is a `is-a` relationship, and `Operators` is clearly not a `Point`. You seriously need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of deriving classes is to make the derived classes more specific. I'm not sure that you would want a class called Operators that is derived from Point.

You might just want to make a definition outside of a class for operator+, or whatever that takes Point objects as parameters.